VoIP push notifications are unreliable in the background or terminated state on iOS
I’m trying to implement reliable VoIP push notifications in my iOS app so that incoming calls are always received, even when the app is in the background or terminated. The issue is that while VoIP pushes work as expected in the foreground, they are unreliable when the app is in the background or terminated. In some cases, no notification arrives at all.
Environment:
Tools: Swift, Xcode
Frameworks: PushKit, CallKit
What’s Happening:
• VoIP notifications work correctly when the app is in the foreground.
• Notifications are intermittent when the app is in the background or terminated.
• No errors appear in the logs, but the pushRegistry(_:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:for:) method isn’t invoked in these cases.
PushKit Registration:
func registerForVoIPPushes() {
    self.voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
    self.voipRegistry?.delegate = self
    self.voipRegistry?.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    registerForVoIPPushes()
    return true
}

Push Registry Handling:
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry,
                  didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload,
                  for type: PKPushType) {
    guard let payloadInfo = payload.dictionaryPayload["data"] as? [AnyHashable: Any] else {
        print("Unidentifiable payload data received")
        return
    }
    print("pushRegistry didReceiveIncomingPushWith \(payloadInfo)")

    guard
        type == .voIP,
        let callId = payloadInfo["callId"] as? String,
        let _ = payloadInfo["deviceId"] as? String,
        let sender = payloadInfo["senderName"] as? String,
        let type = payloadInfo["type"] as? String
    else {
        print("Unknown PushKit notification received")
        return
    }

    let uuid = GlobalMethods().uuidFromString(callId)
    switch type {
    case "NewVoipCallStarted":
        CallManager.shared.processForIncomingCall(sender: sender, uuid: uuid)
    case "CancelVoipCall":
        CallManager.shared.cancelIncomingCall(uuid: uuid)
    default:
        print("Unknown type of voIP notification received")
        return
    }
}

CallKit Integration:
func processForIncomingCall(sender: String, uuid: UUID) {
    let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration()
    configuration.supportsVideo = true
    configuration.includesCallsInRecents = true
    configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]
    configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    configuration.includesCallsInRecents = true
    
    provider = CXProvider(configuration: configuration)
    provider?.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: sender)
    update.hasVideo = true
    
    provider?.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error reporting incoming call: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Incoming call successfully reported.")
        }
    }
}

What I’ve Tried:
• Checked that the VoIP push certificate is valid and uploaded properly.
• Tested sending VoIP pushes with Apple’s Developer Console
• Verified the payload format includes content-available: 1 and apns-priority: 10.
• Ensured the app is registered for PushKit notifications with .voIP push type every time the app launches.
• Confirmed the app has the Background Modes capability enabled, including VoIP.
• Double-checked that the server is sending pushes correctly.
• Checked if the pushRegistry(_:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:for:) method is invoked.
Expected behaviour:
VoIP notifications should always arrive and invoke pushRegistry(_:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:for:),
even if the app is in the background or terminated.
